# Magento 2 Not Showing any Custom Payment Method on Checkout Page

Tags: magento2, payment

I have installed several custom payment methods from magento marketplace. And after enabled them when going to checkout page there is no any custom payment method visible.

Comment: Other payment method is showing ? Like PayPal

Comment: Only checkout/ money order, cash on delivery and zero subtotal checkout so far. Not even PayPal is visible on checkout page.

Comment: Make sure you selected a correct store or website also you are doing indexing or cache flush

Comment: I have selected the correct store and website and even tried on different installations. But result is same

Comment: Indexing or cache flush ?

Comment: @Impunkj still the problem was not solved. those payment modules were work fine with version 2.1.  Even paypal, stripe , square are not visible

Comment: Than need to debug and check